# Separating lavash

Tags: food

I have several Lavash Bread wraps packed together in a plastic bag:

[image: picture of Lavash wraps]

How do I separate the wraps? It seems that when they are packaged and weight is put on them during delivery, they are impossible to separate each one individually.  I always end up throwing away the ones that are stuck together.

Comment: I believe I know what type of wraps you are talking about. However, for those who don't know what they are or know them by another name, can you add a picture or a link of what they look like?

Comment: I agree with @L.B. - a picture would be helpful! I don't even know what a lavash is.

Answer (score 1):

Take the package and roll them up, as you might do with a stack of paper. The wraps will separate so you can remove them one at a time without them sticking together.